# ng-mocks not instantiating tested component

Tags: angular, ng-mocks

I have a Component which I want to test (not mock). It has some public and private fields like `destroy$ = new Subject();` which have no `@Input`. When I call MockRender and get the component via `fixture.point.componentinstance`, the fields are undefined. A console-log inside the constructor does also not get triggered. So what does MockRender do? Why does it not instantiate the component class in a proper way? Or am I using the lib in wrong way? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Hi @Phil, could you share the source code of your test?

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior means you've got a mock. Therefore, something is wrong with setup.

I would recommend to check `beforeEach` to ensure that the `Component` is kept and doesn't fall under mocks due to mocked modules or dependencies:

```
// The Component should be in the first argument of MockBuilder
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(Component, ...));
```